# Extract part of sheet name to cell

Tags: vba, excel, extract, week-number

Part of my sheet name is the date (the part in between the dashes) and I'd like to create a macro that uses the sheet name to give me the number of the week in cell H1 of the sheet.

Sheet name: `BO-D58C2_-20180507-13260132`

I would like to extract in weeknum to cell H1: `20180507`

Do you have any tips for a VBA newbie?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please read the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question, while providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: `Cells(i, 8) = Split(Sheets(i).name, "-")(2)`

Answer (score 2):

use the below function to get the weekdate

```
Function dydate() As String 
sname = ActiveSheet.Name
dydate = Mid(sname, InStr(sname, "_-") + 2, 8)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Range("H1").Value = ActiveSheet.Name

will get the sheets name and put it into a cell for you.  From there, you can any number of RegEx and String replaces to extract only the code between the hyphens, and from there convert it to the Week number.